# Any equivalent to subprocess in PHP?

Tags: php, shell, exec

In Java and Python, you have the `ProcessBuilder` or [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) modules that let you easily start a process using unescaped strings e.g. `["ls", "some unescaped directory name"]` - they also give you powerful tools like access to read from stdout, stderr. Is there any equivalent feature of PHP that is more intelligent and useful than just `exec()`?

Comment: Honestly PHP isn't made to run processes.

Comment: Really? That's what I thought, though in *Modern PHP* they say you can use PHP as a scripting language like Bash - "PHP can also be used to build powerful command-line applications (just like bash, Ruby, Python, and so on). Many PHP developers don’t realize this and miss out on a really exciting feature." - http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033868.do

Comment: not sure if [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) is helpful to you.

Comment: PHP is a scripting language. But used to make web applications, running on the web. It isn't like Python or Java which run on a deeper level on the host machine than PHP.

Comment: not sure but http://phptrends.com/dig_in/Subprocess will help you

Answer (score 4):

The closest equivalent that gives you access to `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`, with two-way communication, would be [`proc_open()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.proc_open.php).

Here's the example from the docs:

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');

$process = proc_open('php', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/error-output.txt

    fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
?>
```

If you only need `stdout` and `stdin`, you can use [`popen()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php).

This is my modified example, since the manual's sucks:

```
<?php
$handle = popen('/path/to/executable', 'r');

$lines = [];
while (!feof($handle))
{
    $lines[] = fgets($handle);
}

pclose($handle);
```

This will read the output of `/path/to/executable` into an array of lines of output.

You also asked about escaping arguments. You can do that with [`escapeshellarg()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php):

```
$escapedArg = escapeshellarg($arg);
```