# How to get and send data from python selenium to php

Tags: python, php, selenium

Excuse my English please.
my system is designed by php and is about connecting together with Amazon auto ordering system(designed by python with selenium)

*Here's the scenario:*
Customer orders the product on my website -> send data to Amazon auto ordering system(designed by python with selenium) -> place the order what customer ordered with automation system -> send data to my system(php)

I am wondering how to send data to python and get data from python
I think send data with Json format to python and get data with Json format from python would work

**Here's python code**
[python code](https://github.com/jasonminsookim/order_automation/blob/master/src/amzn.py)

**Here's temporary php code for sending data to python**

```
function curlPostForOrder($url, $params){
    $ch = curl_init();
        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $url);
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $params['client_token'].":".""); 
        
    $JsonData = json_encode($params['data']);               //Json data post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $JsonData);        //Set Post Data ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);                //Set ReturnTransfer; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                          //Set Post value true ( regular HTTP POST )
        
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        
    $retValue['status'] =true;
    
    $ret= curl_exec($ch);
    error_log($ret);
    if ($ret==false) {
        echo 'Error: Curl Error';
        $retValue['status'] = false;
        $retValue['error_msg'] = curl_error($ch);
    }else{
        $retValue['data'] = json_decode($ret,true);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
        
    return $retValue;
```

**Here's temporary php code for get data from python**

```
function curlPostForRetrieve($url, $params){
    $ch = curl_init();
        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $params['client_token'].":".""); //Set UserPWD;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);                //Set ReturnTransfer; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    
    $retValue['status'] =true;
        
    $ret=curl_exec($ch);
    
    if ($ret==false) {
        echo 'Error: Curl Error';
        $retValue['status'] = false;
        $retValue['error_msg'] = curl_error($ch);
    }else{
        $retValue['data'] = json_decode($ret,true);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
        
    return $retValue;
```

Thank you for your opinions

Comment: I think I answered your last question which is similar, but what exactly are you looking for? just the python code to read the resulting JSON file, or something more specific?

Comment: Thank you for your answer I saw what you answered but  i still don't understand what to do specifically
 I want to know the python code to read the resulting from php and send data to php more in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you can write a simple program to read a JSON file and then write the results out. These are the two functions for doing that:

```py
import json

def read_json(file_path:str) -> dict:
    """Takes in a json file path and returns it's contents"""
    with open(file_path, "r") as json_file:
        content = json.load(json_file)
    return content

def store_json(data:dict, file_path:str):
    """Takes in a python dict and stores it as a .json file"""
    with open(file_path, "w") as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file)
```

`read_json()` takes a file path and returns the python dict with the data. You can then do any necessary preprocessing and feed that into the automation script (`amz.py`). If you need to store the result, take the result from the `amz.py` and store to a JSON file using `store_json()` which takes the data as the first param and file path and just writes the data to the file path.

Comment: Thank you for answering 
One more question,  is it possible for python code to read the result with Json format from php? i think save the Json file when it orders then it's not that the efficient way

Comment: @kenlee I don't know if php has the ability to spawn child or sub-processes (this might be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34892493/any-equivalent-to-subprocess-in-php )  but if it does you could pass the data as a string to python and then use [sys.argv](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-sys-argv-in-python/) and ```json.loads()``` to read it.